# Structural Induction - (zip xs ys)!!n = (xs!!n, ys!!n)

Tags: haskell, induction

Given `n >= 0 and n < min (length xs) (length ys)`
show that `(zip xs ys)!!n = (xs!!n, ys!!n)` with structural Induction over xs.

Is it even possible to do this in a clean way? I cant find any spots where I can use the `Induction Hypothesis`.

Comment: I’m rusty, but I think you can prove `zip xs ys !! 0 = (xs !! 0, ys !! 0)` by equational reasoning and expanding the definitions of `zip` and `!!`, then prove that if `zip xs ys !! n = (xs !! n, ys !! n)` then `zip xs ys !! n + 1 = (xs !! n + 1, ys !! n + 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention it should be structural induction over the length of the list. That is xs becomes (x:xs) in the induction step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll give definitions of `zip` and `!!`:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zip [] [] = []                             -- (zip-1)
zip (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : zip xs ys      -- (zip-2)
zip _ _ = []                               -- (zip-3)

(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
(x : _) !! 0 = x                           -- (!!-1)
(_ : xs) !! n = xs !! (n - 1)              -- (!!-2)
```

Let xs, ys and n arbitrary. Now, suppose that `n >=0` and `n < min (length xs) (length ys)`. We proceed by induction on `xs`.

- Case `xs = []`. Now we do case analysis on `ys`. In both cases, we have that  there's no `n >=0` and `n < min (length xs) (length ys)`. So, this case is trivially true.
- Case `xs = x : xs'`. We proceed by case analysis on `ys`.
- Case `xs = x : xs'` and `ys = []`. Again, we have the theorem trivially true since there's no `n` such that that `n >=0` and `n < min (length xs) (length ys)`.
- Case `xs = x : xs'` and `ys = y : ys'`. Now we do case analysis on `n`.
- Case `xs = x : xs'`, `ys = y : ys'` and `n = 0`. We have that

  ```
  zip (x : xs') (y : ys') !! 0 = {by equation (zip-2)}
  (x,y) : zip xs' ys'     !! 0 = {by equation (!!-1)}
  (x,y)                        = {by equation (!!-1) - backwards}
  ((x : xs') !! 0, (y : ys') !! 0).
  ```
- Case `xs = x : xs'`, `ys = y : ys'` and `n = n' + 1`.

  ```
   zip (x : xs') (y : ys') !! (n + 1) = {by equation zip-2}
   (x,y) : zip xs' ys' !! (n + 1) = {by equation (!!-2)}
   zip xs' ys' !! n               = {by induction hypothesis}
   (xs' !! n , ys' !! n)          = {by equation (!!-2) backwards}
   ((x : xs') !! (n + 1), (y : ys') !! (n + 1))
  ```

  QED

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the final case where you use the IH, wouldnt this be considered Induction over n? Also where did you get the function definitions?

Comment: By no means! The induction is over `xs`. The IH is forall ys. forall n.  n >= 0 /\ n < min (length xs) (length ys) -> zip xs ys !! n = (xs !! n , ys !! n). The need for case analysis on `n` and `ys` is just to "massage" the goal to manipulate it easily using equational reasoning.

Comment: If you think that the answer is fine, please mark it as an answer.